# I currently have no source.list directory or file due to too many failed to fetch errors, how can I resolve?

Tags: software-sources

Give me Please /etc/apt/sources.list

Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

Comment: Are you asking [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: I'm using ubuntu server

Answer (score 0):

Here are mine (stripped of comments).  You will probably want to replace "nz" with the country code of your country.

```
deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted

deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted

deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe

deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse

deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
```